# Sorting R Data Frame in a Specified Order

Tags: r, sorting

Supposing I have (very simple example):

```
df <- data.frame(factor_name  = c("fac_Y", "fac_Y", "fac_Y", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X"),
                 factor_level = c("cherry", "apple", "peach", 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8),
                 value        = c(1, 3, 2, 6, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2))
```

I need to sort `df` based on `factor_name` and `factor_level` *without relying on alphabetic/numerical order* (because in the more complex case I'm working on, the sort order is completely unrelated to these things) such that:

(i)   `factor_name` should be sorted as `(fac_X, fac_Y)`

(ii) within `fac_X`, the `factor_level` sort order should be `(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8)`

(iii)  within `fac_Y`, the `factor_level` sort order should be `("apple", "peach", "cherry")`

So I'll need to supply information by hand about the ordering I want (ie (i)-(iii) above) but I'm unsure how to do that.

I'd like my output therefore to be:

```
df_sorted <- data.frame(factor_name  = c("fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_X", "fac_Y", "fac_Y", "fac_Y"),
                        factor_level = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, "apple", "peach", "cherry"),
                        value        = c(3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1))
```

Can anyone help please?
Thank you.

Comment: It can also work: `df[order(df$factor_name,df$factor_level,df$value),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` after defining the `correct_order`.

```
library(dplyr)

correct_order <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, "apple", "peach", "cherry")
df %>% arrange(factor_name, match(factor_level, correct_order))

#  factor_name factor_level value
#1       fac_X            1     3
#2       fac_X            2     6
#3       fac_X            3     4
#4       fac_X            4     1
#5       fac_X            6     5
#6       fac_X            8     2
#7       fac_Y        apple     3
#8       fac_Y        peach     2
#9       fac_Y       cherry     1
```

You could use the same in base R `order` :

```
df[with(df, order(factor_name, match(factor_level, correct_order))), ]
```

Note that it is not important that `correct_order` should have values for `"fac_X"` first and then `"fac_Y"`. It could be in any order provided values between themselves are maintained. So the above answers would give the same output with :

```
correct_order <- c("apple", "peach", "cherry", 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: I think this works (and still works in a more complex example that I've just tried). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `factor` with `levels` specified

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(factor_name, factor(factor_level,
      levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 'apple', 'peach', 'cherry')))
#   factor_name factor_level value
#1       fac_X            1     3
#2       fac_X            2     6
#3       fac_X            3     4
#4       fac_X            4     1
#5       fac_X            6     5
#6       fac_X            8     2
#7       fac_Y        apple     3
#8       fac_Y        peach     2
#9       fac_Y       cherry     1
```

Comment: Doesn't this rely on being able to sort `fac_Y` in the same order as `fac_X`? In general I won't be able to make that assumption here. Each factor will have its own specific ordering.

Comment: @Alan Do you have completely different levels or do you have case where one of them follows in opposite direction of another

Comment: Completely different - will amend OP to show more clearly

Comment: Ah yes, ok, I can see the logic now. I’ll play with this some more tomorrow. Thank you.